# Remote Desktop Username Logon Failure - Remote Desktop only Passes local Account Domain - Win 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, user-accounts

Remote Desktop Logon Failure - from windows 7 across multiple VPN and NAT, to a Win 08 R2 server.  Logon to the local account has been used and is good.  Multiple users can hit the same account with no issues in same format, as well as mutiple OS.  From my location I can successfully open RDP client using said credentials from Windows 7 Desktop.  Logon Failure is windows 7 laptop, it only passes local account domain, despite various attempts of using ./username, and ip/username, and hostname/username, the destination event viewer repeatedly shows the same result of my laptops name as the domain.

For example, my laptop name is mylaptop, and the remote account is testmgr.  All of the logon attempts from mylaptop, result in logon failure with failed logon as mylaptop\testmgr.

The successful logons show testsystem.cor.int\testmgr, 
Note: The username typed into the windows credential of the successful system did not require entering the destination domain or host name before the user name.  You simply need only type the username of testmgr - voila you are in.

The destination systems are on corporate domains, while none of the systems using the RDP client belong to any domain.  I have hacked on this for weeks, and have sought out guidance from several knowledgeable people with no luck, "....just reload it..."  This should not be that difficult to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

To login with a domain account from a system that does not belong to the same domain, try entering the username using the format `remote_domainname\tesmgr`.

Comment: Workgroup is the default domain.